# Taking an array of objects and placing it in iframe in the form of choices

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, iframe

I am struggling with taking an array of objects which is in my javascript file, and making the objects in the array into a list of choices on my website using html and iframe. I made an iframe id but I'm not sure where to go from there and make something appear on the web page.

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Assessed Assignment A8</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="fruits.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<iframe id="Containers"></iframe>



</body>
     </html>
```

**Javascript code**

```
items = [{"title":"Apple"},{"title":"Orange"},{"title":"Pear"},{"title":"Banana"}];
```

I'm basically trying to make it look like this: https://gyazo.com/9877c7ae75c3d0f2425c31642e48cc01

Cheers

Comment: why do you need an iframe for that?

Comment: I though it would be the best choice for taking an array and placing on a webpage

Comment: no it doesn't :-) you can just use a div for that or better a list (ul). Can you post the whole content of your script file? do you want to use it to insert the data or you want to use an extra script for that?

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't realise that. No thats all of my script, but I want to try this with a separate javascript, like I have now. Yeah I want to use it to insert data :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
I wrote some comments to explain what I mean :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Assessed Assignment A8</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="fruits.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="containers"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

In your fruits.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { // wait for content to load in order to be sure you can select your dom nodes
    var items = [{"title":"Apple"},{"title":"Orange"},{"title":"Pear"},{"title":"Banana"}];
    var myListElement = document.getElementById('containers'); // select your DOM - list element
    for (prop of items) { // traverse your object items
       myListElement.innerHTML += '<li>'+prop.title+'</li>'; // add listitems containing the values from the item object
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this out on js fiddle but nothing happened https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=wLkLbtfj7L

Comment: in jsFiddle you don't need document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { . check this out : https://jsfiddle.net/9pd3dk10/

Comment: np! glad I could help! you have to only just care about "for (prop of items)" . This is ES2015 and not supported in older browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Hi, I have been trying this on my html file and it doesnt work at all. It only works on jsfiddle for some reason?. nothing shows up at all

Comment: on your html file you need the "document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {" again or just put your script before the closing body-tag